# socket.getaddrinfo fails if network started offline

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a problem with a Python script which *should* check if the user is connected to a wifi network with a captive portal. Specifically, the script is long-running, attempting to connect to example.org every 60 seconds.

The problem is that if the network *starts* offline (meaning the  wifi isn't connected at the start of the script), `socket.getaddrinfo` will *always* fail with the error "Name or service not known", even once the wifi is connected, until the Python script is restarted. (This isn't a DNS thing -- all requests fail.)

Because both `urllib` and `requests` use `sockets`, it's totally impossible to download an example page once Python gets into this state.

Is there a way around this or a way to reset `sockets` so it works properly once the network fails?

To be clear, here's a repro:

1. Disconnect wifi
2. Run an interactive Python session
3. `import urllib` and `urllib.open("http://stackoverflow.com/")` -- fails as expected
4. Reconnect wifi
5. `urllib.open("http://example.com/")`

Expected: Returned HTML from example.com
Actual: `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Answer (score -1):

If you're not connected to an access point when running the script, and don't have an IP address assigned to your device `socket.getaddrinfo` will fail. Maybe it's still connecting when you run the script. The domain name cannot be resolved because you are not connected to the network, thus no DNS.

Does it fail when you're actually connected to the network? Does `curl http://icanhazip.com` work at the point when the script fails? Or if you run `ifconfig` does your device have an IP? (I'm assuming you're on a *nix box).

Comment: Yes, it still fails when connected to the network. The problem is that the network state doesn't matter _at all_ if the network isn't connected when the _first_ call is made.

After that first call, I can connect to the network and re-run `socket.getaddrinfo` as many times as I want. It won't work.